# Copy entry from a keepass file to another

Tags: keepass

Is it possible to copy&paste an entry from one keepass file to another? Both are opened.

I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to the other file, but does not work this way.

I also tried to drag and drop a duplicate to the other instance, but it does not work.

I am using V 2.42.1 (latest version)

**Context Menu** showing on right click at the entry:

[image: Context Menu]

Comment: Use the context menu for those items, open both databases in the same KeePass instance (if they are not).

Comment: There is nothing helpful in the context menu

Comment: Either your company enforces some settings or you did disable them yourself. Part of the context menu normally are option to copy entries to clipboard (Ctrl+Shift+C in the Clipboard sub menu) and options to export an entry (in the "Selected Entry" sub menu). Check options and the tab "policies" for "Copy Whole Entries".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The options to copy/paste entries from one database to another do not appear in the context menu anymore as of KeePass v2.43.

You can use instead the top menu, or the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Make sure you do the paste operation before the clipboard timer expires.

[image: copy screenshot]
[image: paste screenshot]

---

If you get this message while copying the entry, this is probably because the corresponding policy is disabled:

> This operation is disallowed by the application policy. Ask your administrator to allow this operation.
>
> The following policy flag is required:
>
> Copy Whole Entries.

[image: msgbox screenshot]

[image: options screenshot]

Comment: Even works with selections of multiple entries, great!

Comment: Very detailed post, Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 4):

in previous versions it was possible to copy entries from on e database to another. Unfortunately, this feature recently has disappeared from the context menu.
Ctrl+Shift+C / Ctrl+Shift+V still work!